# How does one stop grails from executing in Intellij?

Tags: grails, intellij-idea

I can't see where/how to stop `grails` from executing in `Intellij`.

I started it by doing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>G</kbd>, and gave `run-app` command, but there is no `grails stop-app`, and I never pressed the `Intellij` green Run arrow, so?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure if it graceful or not, but there is a small skull button to kill the process in the same window which appeared after you do "ctrl-alt-g run-app" (left top corner)

Comment: Thanks Dennis, I see the skull icon and it does stop it when doing the run-app.  Per my other comment to Gregg, do you have a preference as how to start Grails ... does it matter for debug, etc?  Thanks again.

Comment: @Ray Running/debugging grails using run configuration is easier than using groovy console and more aligned to what IntelliJ provides for any other types of apps

Answer (score 3):

Look at the bottom of IntelliJ.  There should at least be a tab that says Run (or Debug).  If you click it you should see the running console and icons on the left to click it.  If  not, show us a screenshot of your app running in IntelliJ.

Comment: Thanks Gregg.  It looks like there are two ways.  If I start grails using the run-app command, then I need to kill it using the skull icon in the upper left corner of the console, as Denis indicated.  If I start it using the green run button -- which didn't work before for some reason when I started my project but is working now -- then the buttons to stop/pause/kill do appear at the left of the console.  I'm new to IntelliJ ... do you prefer to use one mechanism to run grails vs. the other.  Is using the green run button required to do break-points, etc?